# Grub package failed to install in ubuntu installation

Tags: uefi, grub-efi

I tried installing ubuntu to my external toshiba hard drive. What i did was

> made a swap of 16Gb
>   ext4 / of 165Gb 
>   rest left as free space.

Then some installation happend and got below error.
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the grub boot loader 
Please help me on this installation.

Answer (score 0):

This error message has been cropping up a lot lately, and it seems to have a number of different causes. Some questions that mention it include:

- [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 --- grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400400/ubuntu-12-04-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-to-install-into-target)
- [Ubuntu 16.10 Dual Boot error - 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 install: grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485008/ubuntu-14-04-install-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-to-install-into-target)

One common cause seems to be related to a failure to create an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (this will normally be an issue only if you use the "something else" installation option). I've seen this occasionally on systems that use NVMe "disks" rather than conventional hard disks, too.

For a workaround, look into Boot Repair or rEFInd, as described in my answer to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930525/installed-ubuntu-but-when-i-boot-it-always-brings-me-to-grub-rescue)